# Errors appearing on separate target

Tags: xcode, target

I have created a new target for the purpose of making a lite version of my app. However, when I import my code into the new target, I receive over 10 errors! Keep in mind the initial target works flawlessly.

Here is my list of errors. Any thoughts?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the CoreData framework to your new target? It looks like it isn't finding any of the headers from CoreData.